# Click with append is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with attaching an onclick event with an appended anchor. When I click on a row it is not giving me the iterative id.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= oRes.projects.length; i++) {
    jQuery('<a/>', {
        href: "#_",
        html: oRes.projects[i]['project_name'] + "<span>" + oRes.projects[i]['project_duration'] + "</span>" + i,
        class: "setup-button projectItems",
        "data-role": "button",
        "data-iconpos": "left",
        "data-projectId": oRes.projects[i]['project_id'],
        "click": function() {
            alert(i);
         }
    }).appendTo('#myprojectList');

    $('#myprojectList a').button();
}
```

Comment: Well for one you're iterating `oRes.projects.length + 1` times because of the `<=` in the for condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "iterative id" ? the value of i or projectId ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` will always be equal to your `array.length`, you can use the index of the button `$(this).index()` (same value as `i` iterates by 1 from 0 to array length).

```
[...]
"click": function() {
    alert( 'button:' + $(this).index()  );
 }
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yiernehr/ttFtb/5/)